# toArray method not working in class that extends ArrayList<>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, extends

i have a class called "Table" which extends ArrayList. Within this class i have a method called toArray(). Whenever i compile i get the error: "toArray() in Table cannot implement toArray() in java.util.List return type void is not compatible with java.lang.Object[]"

Here is the Table class:

```
public class Table extends ArrayList<Row>
{
public ArrayList<String> applicants;
public String appArray[];
public String appArray2[] = {"hello", "world","hello","world","test"};

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Table
 */
public Table()
{
    applicants = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void addApplicant(String app)
{
    applicants.add(app);
    toArray();
}

public void toArray()
{
    int x = applicants.size();
    if (x == 0){ } else{
    appArray=applicants.toArray(new String[x]);}
}

public void list() //Lists the arrayList
{
    for (int i = 0; i<applicants.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(applicants.get(i));
    }
}

public void listArray() //Lists the Array[]
{
    for(int i = 0; i<appArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(appArray[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestions will be really appreciated!

Comment: First of, start changing to`if (x != 0) appArray=applicants.toArray(new String[x]);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

General advice: do not extend from classes that are not intended for client subclassing. `ArrayList` is an example of such a class. Instead define your own class that implements the `List` interface and contains an `ArrayList` to reuse its functions. This is the *Decorator* pattern.

Specific advice: `toArray` is a method defined in `ArrayList` and you can't override it with a different return type.

Comment: Or better: extend `AbstractList`(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html)

Comment: Or even better: [`ForwardingList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is because [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), which `ArrayList` implements, already declares a [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) method. That method returns `Object[]`, which is different from your method's return type of `void`, so it doesn't work as an override.

Your method seems to be doing something completely different, so the best solution is to just rename it.

Answer (score 1):

You are overloading a method called toArray.

Try calling it something else, like convertToMyArray()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to accomplish but your method should look something like this.

```
@Override
public Object[] toArray(){
      return applicants.toArray();
   }
}
```